# Scss accessing nested data

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I'm trying to figure out how to access nested variables.  I currently have something like the following:

```
@mixin password-reset-modal-props {
    color: map-deep-get($modal-settings, 'password-reset', 'header', 'color');
    font-size: map-deep-get($modal-settings, 'password-reset', 'header', 'font');
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Bold';
}
```

and accessed using:

```
@include password-reset-modal-props
```

I would like to use a nested variable so that I can group them together.  I was thinking of something like:

```
@mixin password-reset-modal-props {
    header: {
        color: map-deep-get($modal-settings, 'password-reset', 'header', 'color');
        font-size: map-deep-get($modal-settings, 'password-reset', 'header', 'size');
        font-family: map-deep-get($modal-settings, 'password-reset', 'header', 'font');
    },
    label: {
        font-family: map-deep-get($modal-settings, 'password-reset', 'header', 'font');
    },
}
```

and access like this:

```
@include password-reset-modal-props.header;
```

I know my code is invalid cause I get an error and was wondering if its possible?  I'm Googling but haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a parameter and [@if/@else](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if) statements:

```
@mixin password-reset-modal-props($element) {
    @if ($element == 'header') {
        color: map-deep-get($modal-settings, 'password-reset', 'header', 'color');
        font-size: map-deep-get($modal-settings, 'password-reset', 'header', 'size');
        font-family: map-deep-get($modal-settings, 'password-reset', 'header', 'font');

    } @else if ($element== 'label'){
        font-family: map-deep-get($modal-settings, 'password-reset', 'header', 'font');
    }
}

.test {
    @include password-reset-modal-props(header);
}
```